# How to setup Bind9 on ubuntu server 20.04 /DNS issue- bind9

Tags: server, dns, 20.04, bind

I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, yesterday, how do I setup bind9 to point to my domain Sturtz.ml, I got my domain with Freenom and I am using Cloudflare I will share the files if you ask for,
I got it to the point where it is connected to Cloudflare, I know this because it is giving me a Cloudflare screen(IMG 1), but it will not get to my server. This is what the screen looks like
[image: IMG 1]
When I try to restart bind9 with `systemctl reload bind9` I get this, `named.service is not active, cannot reload.`, When I type `/etc/init.d/named status` I get

```
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-15 16:24:00 UTC; 2h 41min ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
    Process: 55460 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 55460 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: creating TCP socket: address in use
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: listening on IPv4 interface enp0s25, 192.168.0.5#53
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: creating TCP socket: address in use
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: unable to listen on any configured interfaces
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: loading configuration: failure
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: exiting (due to fatal error)
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 19:02:52 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

Now when I go to http://sturtz.ml I get 
[image: IMG2]

But when I goto http://www.sturtz.ml I get [image: IMG1]

Comment: Does this solve your problem?  https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/set-up-local-dns-resolver-ubuntu-20-04-bind9

Comment: I think so, let me give it a try

Comment: When I run the command ```sudo systemctl enable bind9``` I get ```Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on alias name or linked unit file: bind9.service```

Comment: Is this something I can just ignore?

Comment: Ollie, No it did not work.

Comment: The [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns) might be of assistance, and it it isn't let's fix it. Otherwise we need more information, like config files and such.

Comment: is there a way for me to reset the files back to the way they where?

Comment: @DougSmythies I tried that and it did not work. What files do you need?

Comment: Bind does not work out of the box, as such is not possible. You should have several configuration files specific to your situation/requirements. Post those files. For example, and for my, internal only DNS, `/etc/bind/db.smythies.com`, `/etc/bind/db.192.` (because I use 192.111.0.0/24 internally), `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`, `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`.

Comment: How do I configure the files? What files do you need me to share?

Comment: What files do you need to help me?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do here?  Since your site is served by CLoudFlare you have to set the DNS *there* not at BIND9

Comment: I have done that, I now need to point my server to cloud flare

Comment: I also need to fix, bind9 and Named